# Gradle and firebase issues in my Flutter project

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, gradle

I made a Flutter project and added all the necessary dependencies for the Firebase database, after making a successful connection I turned off my computer, 1 day later my code no longer runs and i get the error below:[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh7v5.png)

i checked all the dependencies & versions even did a flutter clean, since it didn't work i ran "flutter buil apk --debug --verbose" to try an find the issue but i got many red lines that i did not understand since IAM new to flutter

Comment: Can you show which dependencies and versions you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to clear the project cache by running:

```
flutter pub cache clean
```

Comment: thank you so much all the errors disappeared

Comment: Hi, could you mark my answer as a solution to close this thread.